# Selecting from a database table, then filtering and ordering by two different sets of values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

So I have a page with two checkboxlists (C# ASP.net), one with a short list of demands and one with a list of wishes. Multiple values can be checked in both lists. In the database I have a table called 'Info' with the columns 'ID', 'Systems', 'Demands' and 'Wishes'. It looks a bit like the first table in the top left corner here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18mybB32cAMSi7dX49CFyZB2CrS3yI_MoynM4pr8acew/edit#gid=0

The aim of the page is to allow the user to pick demands and wishes, and for the page to return a list of possible systems. The list will be filtered by demands (If a system doesnt meet a demand it doesnt need to be shown at all) and then ordered by **the amount of wishes each system satisfies**.

The code I have so far can only filter the database by demands (Which are selected in CheckBoxList1). The wishes are selected in CheckBoxList1. I'm just having trouble adapting the existing query to also include the ordering by the amount of matched demands. Is it possible with a single query? If not, what should I change?

```
string query = "SELECT DISTINCT System FROM Info";
        int numSelected = 0;
        string condition = string.Empty;

        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                numSelected = numSelected + 1;
            }
        }
        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            condition += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}', ", item.Value) : "";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
        {
            condition = string.Format(" where Demand IN ({0}) GROUP BY System HAVING count(*) = {1}", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 2), numSelected);
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + condition);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem, I really appreciate it! I'll try to answer any questions to the best of my ability.

Comment: How does `item.Value` get set?  If it's the user, you're still open to SQL Injection.  To make something like this safe, you have to add a list of parameter markers, then replace them with the values.  Or alternate tactics - there are several answers around here that show stored procs that will safely take a comma-separated list and turn them into a table-variable in SQL Server.  You need to run the two comparisons as separate subqueries, or you'll get strange results.

Comment: Nothing gets passed through the url, I'm reading the values directly from CheckBoxList1.Items

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the problem right. Try this

Change your query

```
 string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Systeem, count(*) FROM Eisen";
```

Add the order by clause

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition)/* && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition2)*/)
        {
            condition = string.Format(" where Eis IN ({0}) GROUP BY Systeem HAVING count(*) = {1}", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 2), numSelected/*, condition2.Substring(0, condition2.Length - 2)*/);
        }
        string orderBy = string.Format(" ORDER BY count(*)");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + condition + orderBy);
```

Try to construct the query like below and check

```
SELECT system 
, system +  ' (Fulfills ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, COUNT(*)) + ' wishes)' AS [Eligible systems]
,(SELECT Demands + ',' AS [text()]  FROM info WHERE system =i.system FOR XML PATH('')) AS Demands
,(SELECT wishes + ',' AS [text()]  FROM info WHERE system =i.system FOR XML PATH('')) AS Wishes
FROM info i
WHERE Demands in ('1','2','3')
AND wishes in ('1','2','3','4')
GROUP BY system
Order By COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to translate the column-names and tablename in the code. They match their equivalents in the google document now. At the moment, the code only checks CheckBoxList1 for which demands have been selected. It also needs to check CheckBoxList2 for which wishes have been selected, and then order the list of systems by how many wishes each system fulfills. In the end, the page should behave like the blue/green table. I select demands and wishes and get a list of systems in return.

Comment: Even just a query using {selected values of checkboxlist1} and {selected values of checkboxlist2} as placeholders would help me immensely. I feel like I'm very close to the answer, I just need to solve the SQL.

Comment: Can you check the above updated statement and comment?